# How can I run unit tests in the same way that msbuild runs them?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, mstest

I'm trying to understand why a unit test fails on the build server with msbuild when it passes everywhere else, including that same machine from within Visual Studio.  Naturally it is some sort of environment thing (location of files, directories, etc).

What I want to do is, instead of going through a long painful build process every time I go through my trial/error process, I would like to know how to just run the unit tests from, say, the command line (it doesn't look like it uses mstest.exe...  besides, mstest.exe works), so I can rapidly churn through some experiments.  Thanks!

Comment: [Run automated tests from the command line using MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx)

Comment: [Walkthrough: using the command-line test utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx)

Comment: MSbuild can’t run unit tests, unless it calls other command/app to run tests in the target. (http://theflightlessgeek.co.nz/thoughts/2014/2/18/running-mstest-unit-tests-via-an-msbuild-script)
So, how do you run unit tests during the build? Provide the details code of your project file.

Comment: What's the detail code of your project file?